# How to delete a subgraph of a boost graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

The following code is taken from [boost family tree example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/graph/example/family-tree-eg.cpp)

I am looking for a simple way to delete subgraph

```
enum family { Jeanie, Debbie, Rick, John, Amanda, Margaret, Benjamin, N };
int main()
{
  using namespace boost;
  const char *name[] = { "Jeanie", "Debbie", "Rick", "John", "Amanda",
    "Margaret", "Benjamin"
  };

  adjacency_list <> g(N);
  add_edge(Jeanie, Debbie, g);
  add_edge(Jeanie, Rick, g);
  add_edge(Jeanie, John, g);
  add_edge(Debbie, Amanda, g);
  add_edge(Rick, Margaret, g);
  add_edge(John, Benjamin, g);

  // some code

  // Rick and his family left - I want to remove them from the chart

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done in this example. Enum family is the index in vertex container in the graph. So by removing Rick would John become be Rick.

However if the definition of the graph is changed to use values of enum a solution would be following.

```
enum family { Jeanie, Debbie, Rick, John, Amanda, Margaret, Benjamin, N };
const char *name[] = { "Jeanie", "Debbie", "Rick", "John", "Amanda",
                       "Margaret", "Benjamin"
                     };
typedef boost::adjacency_list <boost::vecS
                             , boost::vecS
                             , boost::bidirectionalS
                             , family> Graph;

struct VisitorBFS : public boost::default_bfs_visitor {
    VisitorBFS(
        std::vector<boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor>& container
    )
    : container(container) {}

    template <class Vertex, class Graph>
    void discover_vertex(const Vertex& v, const Graph& g) const
    {
        container.push_back(v);
    }

    std::vector<boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor>& container;
};

void printFamily(const Graph& g)
{
    using namespace boost;
    graph_traits <Graph>::vertex_iterator i, end;
    graph_traits <Graph>::adjacency_iterator ai, a_end;

    for (boost::tie(i, end) = vertices(g); i != end; ++i) {
        std::cout << name[g[*i]];
        boost::tie(ai, a_end) = adjacent_vertices(*i, g);
        if (ai == a_end)
            std::cout << " has no children";
        else
            std::cout << " is the parent of ";
        for (; ai != a_end; ++ai) {
            std::cout << name[g[*ai]];
            if (boost::next(ai) != a_end)
                std::cout << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using namespace boost;

    Graph g;
    add_vertex(Jeanie, g);
    add_vertex(Debbie, g);
    add_vertex(Rick, g);
    add_vertex(John, g);
    add_vertex(Amanda, g);
    add_vertex(Margaret, g);
    add_vertex(Benjamin, g);

    add_edge(Jeanie, Debbie, g);
    add_edge(Jeanie, Rick, g);
    add_edge(Jeanie, John, g);
    add_edge(Debbie, Amanda, g);
    add_edge(Rick, Margaret, g);
    add_edge(John, Benjamin, g);

    printFamily(g);

    // Rick and his family left - I want to remove them from the chart

    // First, find a subgraph from vertex Rick. Algorithm breadth_first_search
    // also goes through the start vertex, so Rick is included in result.
    std::vector<graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor> vertexes;
    breadth_first_search(g, Rick, visitor(VisitorBFS(vertexes)));

    // Then remove incoming edges because they are not removed automatically
    // along with vertexes, then remove vertexes. 
    for (std::vector<graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor>::iterator it = vertexes.begin(); it != vertexes.end();  ++it) {
        clear_in_edges(*it, g);
        remove_vertex(*it, g);
    }

    printFamily(g); 

    return 0;
}
```